# Stretching Words

Tags: code-golf, string, subsequence

Write a program or function that duplicates letters in a word, so that all the duplicated letters arranged from left to right in the word would form the input array.

For example:

```
input: chameleon, [c,a,l,n]
output: cchaamelleonn
```

### Input

- The starting word (e.g. `chameleon`)
- An array of characters (`[c,a,l,n]`) or a string to represent an array (`caln`), or something similar
- Input can be through function parameters, STDIN or language equivalents
- All inputs will be lower-case letters (a-z)

### Output

- The changed word
- If there are multiple solutions, any can be printed

  ```
  input: banana [n,a]  
  possible outputs: bannaana, banannaa
                       |-|---------|-|--->[n,a]
  ```
- You may assume that the input word (not necessarily the array) will have the letters in the array (in order)
- You may also assume that the inputs have no consecutive letters which are the same (NOT apple, geek, green, glass, door...)

### Examples

```
input: abcdefghij, [a,b,c]
output: aabbccdefghij

input: lizard, [i,a,r,d]
output: liizaarrdd

input: coconut, [c,o]
ouput: ccooconut or coccoonut or ccocoonut

input: onomatopoeia, [o,o,a,o,o]
output: oonoomaatoopooeia

input: onomatopoeia, [o,a,o]
output: oonomaatoopoeia or onoomaatoopoeia or oonomaatopooeia etc.
```

Shortest program wins!

Leaderboard (thanks to Martin Büttner for the snippet)

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 51984; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";

/* App */

var answers = [], page = 1;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      if (data.has_more) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });
}

getAnswers();

var SIZE_REG = /\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;
var NUMBER_REG = /\d+/;
var LANGUAGE_REG = /^#*\s*([^,]+)/;

function shouldHaveHeading(a) {
  var pass = false;
  var lines = a.body_markdown.split("\n");
  try {
    pass |= /^#/.test(a.body_markdown);
    pass |= ["-", "="]
              .indexOf(lines[1][0]) > -1;
    pass &= LANGUAGE_REG.test(a.body_markdown);
  } catch (ex) {}
  return pass;
}

function shouldHaveScore(a) {
  var pass = false;
  try {
    pass |= SIZE_REG.test(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0]);
  } catch (ex) {}
  return pass;
}

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  answers = answers.filter(shouldHaveScore)
                   .filter(shouldHaveHeading);
  answers.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = +(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0],
        bB = +(b.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0];
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  answers.forEach(function (a) {
    var headline = a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];
    //console.log(a);
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    var num = headline.match(NUMBER_REG)[0];
    var size = (headline.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0];
    var language = headline.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1];
    var user = getAuthorName(a);
    if (size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = size;
    ++place;
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.share_link);
    answer = jQuery(answer)
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    languages[language] = languages[language] || {lang: language, user: user, size: size, link: a.share_link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @AlexA. only one instance because otherwise the array formed by the duplicate letters would be `[c,o,c,o]`, rather than `[c,o]`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, reading it again that's obvious. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing this got quite a lot of answers, and many in the same languages, would you be interested in [adding the leaderboard snippet](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5139/8478)? If so, I'm happy to edit it in and amend the answers that don't use the required header format.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I forgot about that! Added. I had to change `#answer-list` and `#language-list` width to `50%` to avoid overlapping columns in your snippet.

Comment: @StretchManiac That's because some of the answers contain links in their headers which they shouldn't. I'll fix them.

Comment: "You may also assume that the inputs have no consecutive letters which are the same (NOT apple, geek, green, glass, door...)" both inputs or just the first one? There's an example with "ooaoo" as second input and my code breaks in this case.

Comment: Clarification (see my `bash`+`sed` answer): Is it illegal for `banana, na` => `baannana`?  I believed that "You may assume that all inputs will have the letters in the array (in order)" is meant to _permit_, but not _require_, answers to process both lists sequentially, but @manatwork interpreted it differently.

Comment: Is there a maximum length on either piece of input?

Comment: @aragaer that is only the first input, not the array, I'll clarify that.

Comment: @TobySpeight that sentence was meant to merely state that the input possible, for example there would be no `banana ,[t,x]`. In your example, the duplicated letters would form `[a,n]`, not `[n,a]`. I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: I'm still not completely sure - is `banana, na` => `baannana` allowed?  Or am I only allowed `bannaana`, `bannanaa` or `banannaa` for that input?

Comment: @TobySpeight No. That is not allowed (your first sentence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
s+L&@d<Q1.(QZz
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2BL%26%40d%3CQ1.(Q0z&input=onomatopoeia%0A%5B%22o%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22o%22%2C%22o%22%5D&debug=0)

Input style:

```
banana
["b","a","n","a"]
```

Explanation:

```
s+L&@d<Q1.(Q0z
                  Implicit: z = input(); Q = eval(input())
 +L          z    Map (lambda d) over z, adding the result to each character.
    @d<Q1         Intersection of d with Q[:1], up to the first element of Q.
   &              Logical and - if the first arg is truthy, evaluate and
                  return the second arg, otherwise return first arg.
         .(Q0     Q.pop(0)
                  The addition will either be the empty string, for the empty
                  intersection, or the character that was Q[0] otherwise.

s                 Concatenate and print.
```

Answer (score 44):

## Brainfuck, <s>46</s> 45 (63 with printable characters in input)

Compatible with Alex Pankratov's [bff](http://swapped.cc/#!/bff) (brainfuck interpreter used on SPOJ and ideone) and Thomas Cort's [BFI](http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/BFI.c) (used on Anarchy Golf).

The printable version takes the array first as a string, followed by a tab, followed by the starting string with no trailing newline.

[Demonstration](http://ideone.com/4d2L5E) on ideone.

```
-[+>,---------]
<[++++++++<]
<,+
[
  -.
  [>+>-<<-]
  >>
  [
    <[>+<-]
  ]
  <[.[-]]
  ,+
]
```

We can save some bytes by using `\x00` as a separator instead of tab:

```
,[>,]
<[<]
<,+
[
  -.
  [>+>-<<-]
  >>
  [
    <[>+<-]
  ]
  <[.[-]]
  ,+
]
```

Comment: That feeling when BF is shorter than my Python code.. :(

Comment: I usually don't care for Brainfuck, but this is awesome!

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
rr{_C#)/(C@s}fC
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rr%7B_C%23)%2F(C%40s%7DfC&input=onomatopoeia%20oao)

#### How it works

```
rr              e# Read two whitespace-separated tokens from STDIN.
  {         }fC e# For each character C in the second string.
   _            e#   Duplicate the first string.
    C#          e#   Compute the index of the character in the string.
      )/        e#   Add 1 and split the string in slice of that size.
        (       e#   Shift out the first slice.
         C      e#   Push the character.
          @     e#   Rotate the remainder of the string in top of the stack.
           s    e#   Stringify (concatenate the slices).
```

Comment: It's a battle of the CJams! You and Sp both have 15 byte CJam answers, and 15 is currently the shortest. :)

Comment: @AlexA. Just wait for Pyth. You just wait...

Comment: Sounds like you'd better learn Pyth. ;)

Answer (score 12):

## C, 62 bytes

```c
f(char*s,char*c){while(*s-*c||putchar(*c++),*s)putchar(*s++);}
```

Well, this is surprisingly competetive.

We define a function `f(char*, char*)` that takes the string as its first input and the array of characters to duplicate as its second input.

Some testing code:

```c
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    f("onomatopeia", "oao");
    return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```c
oonomaatoopeia
```

Try it [online](http://ideone.com/IVHCqG)!

If it is acceptable to submit a macro rather than a function, the following `#define g(s,c)` is just **58 bytes**, but requires `s` and `c` to be actual pointers:

```c
#define g(s,c)while(*s-*c||putchar(*c++),*s)putchar(*s++);
```

Comment: Thanks for making me look up the [comma operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). That's useful!

Comment: Suggest `write(1,c++,*s==*c)` instead of `*s-*c||putchar(*c++)`

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
rr{:X/(XX+@X*}/
```

An alternative CJam approach. [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rr%7B%3AX%2F%28XX%2B%40X*%7D%2F&input=onomatopoeia%20oao)

### Explanation

For each character in the second string, we do two things.

1. Split the current suffix of the string by the character, e.g. `"beeper" "e"  ->  ["b" "" "p" "r"]`
2. Uncons the first string in the array, insert two of the character, then rejoin the rest of the array with the character, e.g. `"b" "ee" "eper"`. The last string is the new suffix.

Answer (score 9):

## Retina, 33 bytes

[More information about Retina.](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina)

```
+`(?=(.))(((.)(?<!\4.))+\n)\1
$1$2
```

This expects the two strings on STDIN, separated by a newline.

For counting purposes, each line goes into a separate file, `\n` should be replaced with an actual newline character (0x0A). If you actually want to test this, it's more convenient to put this in a single file where `\n` remains as it is and then invoke Retina with the `-s` option before passing the file.

### Explanation

*(Outdated... I managed to get rid of the marker... I'll update this later.)*

Each pair of lines is a regex substitution (first line the pattern, second line the substitution).

```
^
#
```

This puts a `#` as a marker at the start of the input string.

```
+`#(.*?(.))(.*\n)\2
$1$2#$3
```

This finds the first letter in the input (after the marker) corresponding to the next letter to be duplicated, duplicates that letter, moves the marker behind it, and drops the first character of the second string. The `` +` `` at the front tells Retina to do this repeatedly until the string stops changing (in this case, because the second string is empty and all required letters have been duplicated).

```
#
<empty>
```

Finally, we clean up the string by dropping the marker.

Comment: I figured that retina would have a nice solution, and I was right, because you found one. Also, when I first skimmed your description, I read the end as "we clean up the string by dropping the *mic*."

Comment: @mbomb007 I was hoping to get rid of the "mic" by only duplicating individual letters that don't have any duplicates after them, but I can't do it in less than 33 bytes. (There's a broken 28 byte version in the revision history.)

Comment: @mbomb007 FYI, I did manage to remove the marker now, but the byte count is still the same. This still looks golfable though.

Comment: As an aside, I just realized that Retina doesn't have a page on https://esolangs.org

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, I'm aware. I'll probably add one after I've implemented a few of the more important outstanding features.

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 61

```python
def f(s,l):b=s[:1]==l[:1];return s and-~b*s[0]+f(s[1:],l[b:])
```

A greedy recursive solution. Saves to `b` whether the first letter of the string `s` is the first letter of the string `l` of letters to double. If so, take one of that letter and prepend it to the recursive call with the rest of `s`, removing the first element from `l`. If not `b`, do the same but don't double the letter and don't remove from `l`.

The code checks `s[:1]==l[:1]` rather than `s[0]==l[0]` to avoid an index-out-of-bounds error when `s` or `l` is empty.

Answer (score 7):

## Prolog, <s>95</s> <s>83</s> <s>79</s> 56 bytes

```
d([A|S],H):-put(A),H=[A|T],put(A),d(S,T);d(S,H).
d(_,_).
```

Example:

```
d(`chameleon`,`caln`).
```

returns

```
cchaamelleonn
```

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to Oliphaunt

Edit2: Saved 20 bytes using the deprecated `put/1` SWI-Prolog predicate instead of `writef`. Saved one byte replacing the recursion end predicate `d([],_).` to `d(_,_).`. Won't work if the ordering of the two definitions of `d` is swapped though, but we don't care about that in golfed code. Saved another 2 bytes removing the parenthesis around `H=[A|T],put(A),d(S,T)`

Comment: I'm not really sure why this got downvoted. Maybe add some explanation to your code?

Comment: You can save four bytes by unifying implicitly: `H=[A|T]`. Also, why not make it a little more readable by replacing the spaces with newlines?

Comment: @Oliphaunt Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't see this slight optimization after I originally modified my code to use the H=[A|T] clause.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>83</s> <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 65 Bytes

No real special tricks here. `x` is the string, `y` is the array of characters that are duplicated. <s>To clarify if this doesn't copy properly, the first indentation level is a space, the next is a tab.</s>

*Edit 1: Saved 9 bytes by using string manipulation instead of pop().*

*Edit 2: Saved 2 bytes by using `-~` to increment `g` by 1.*

*Edit 3: Saved 7 bytes by using `y[:1]` trick, thanks to xnor for this!*

```python
def f(x,y,s=''):
 for c in x:g=y[:1]==c;s+=c*-~g;y=y[g:]
 print s
```

[Check it out here.](http://ideone.com/itjEAj)

Properly formatted and explained:

```python
def f(x,y,s=''):           # Defining a function that takes our input,
                           # plus holds a variable we'll append to.
  for c in x:              # For every character in 'x', do the following:
    g = y[:1] == c         # Get the first element from the second string, will
                           # return an empty string if there's nothing left.
                           # Thanks to xnor for this trick!
    s += c * -~g           # Since int(g) would either evaluate to 0 or 1, we
                           # use the -~ method of incrementing g to multiply
                           # the character by 1 or 2 and append it to 's'
    y = y[g:]              # Again, since int(g) would either evaluate to 0
                           # or 1, use that to cut the first value off y, or
                           # keep it if the characters didn't match.
  print s                  # Print the string 's' we've been appending to.
```

Comment: "You may assume that all inputs will have the letters in the array (in order)." That should save you quite a few bytes.

Comment: You can get the first element from a possibly-empty string as `y[:1]`.

Comment: I now realize that you can't save as many as I thought because of how you're doing it with `y=y[g:]`, so "quite a few" is quite an exaggeration.

Comment: @Vioz- I was thinking `y[:1]==c`. Does that work?

Comment: @xnor Yes, it does if I take the letters that need replacing instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

#### Excel VBA, 110 bytes

This is my first entry to CodeGolf so I hope this is ok.

You enter the input word in A1 and then the letters to be replaced in B1 and the resulting word is displayed in a message box.

```
w = Cells(1, 1)
l = Cells(2, 1)
For i = 1 To Len(w)
x = Left(w, 1)
R = R + x
If InStr(l, x) > 0 Then
R = R + x
End If
w = Right(w, Len(w) - 1)
Next
MsgBox R
```

Comment: If VBA isn't indentation-sensitive, you could get rid of all of the indents and save a few bytes. I think you can also get rid of all of the spaces after commas and around operators. Ought to save you a few bytes.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Thanks for your edit. I pressed rollback just to see what it would do. Not sure if that made you lose points or something for your edit?

Comment: Nope, I still have the +2, though I did get confused for a bit. You might want to roll back again; at least according to three highish-rep people, it was a good edit.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I agree I liked the edit. Think I just rolledbacked one too many times.

Comment: I can't tell. Mobile doesn't exactly display things nicely. Ultimately, though, what matters is the code, not the formatting.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 47 bytes

```
(a,b)=>a.replace(/./g,d=>b[0]!=d?d:d+b.shift())
```

Taking advantage of some ES6 features.

Comment: Does this work correctly for `onomatopoeia`, `oao`?

Comment: @AlexA. Outputs: "oonoomaatoopooeiaa". Ah, I understand. Will fix

Comment: Fixed, I think. Added a lot of characters :(

Comment: Instead of `b.indexOf(d)==0`, try `~b.search(d)`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `search` is only applicable on strings. Had to change b to an array

Comment: It would be shorter to use `replace` instead of converting to an array and mappning: `(a,b)=>a.replace(/./g,d=>!b.indexOf(d)?d+b.splice(0,1):d)`.

Comment: @NinjaBearMonkey That's a great idea, thanks

Comment: @edc65 splice modifies `b` in place, which is why I'm using it. If I just used a zero index, it would only replace the first character. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you comment...

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
sm?+d.(QZqd&QhQdz
```

[Live demo.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%3F%2Bd.(QZqd%26QhQdz&input=chameleon%0A%5B%27c%27%2C%27l%27%2C%27a%27%2C%27n%27%5D&debug=1)

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Jakube.

### Explanation:

```
                z  Read the first line of input.
 m                 For each character in that line
  ?      qd&QhQ    If (?) the first char of the stretch list (`&QhQ`) 
                   and the current character are equal,
   +d.(QZ          Then double the current character and pop an element off
                   the stretch list.
               d   Otherwise, just return the same character.
s                  Join all the characters together.
```

### Original version:

```
jkm?+d.(QZqd&QhQdz
```

[Live demo for original.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jkm%3F%2Bd.(QZqd%26QhQdz&input=chameleon%0A%5B%27c%27%2C%27l%27%2C%27a%27%2C%27n%27%5D&debug=1)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 42 bytes

```
(a:b)#e@(c:d)|a==c=a:a:b#d|1<2=a:b#e
a#_=a
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> "coconut" # "co"
"ccooconut"
*Main> "lizard" # "iard"
"liizaarrdd"
*Main> "onomatopoeia" # "ooaoo"
"oonoomaatoopooeia"
```

How it works:

If one string is empty, the result is the first string. Else: if the first characters of the strings match, take it two times and append a recursive call with the tails of the strings. If the characters don't match, take the first character of the first string and append a recursive call with the tail of the first string and the same second string.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
u|pH<GJxGH>GJwz
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%7CpH%3CGJhxGH%3EGJwz&input=coconut%0Aco&debug=0)

This is quite hacky. Stack-based languages might have an advantage here.

#### Explanation

```
                   implicit: z = 1st input line, w = 2nd
u             wz   reduce, start with G = z
                   for each H in w, update G to:
        xGH          index of H in G
       h             +1
      J              store in J
    <GJ              substring: G[:J] (everything before index J)
  pH                 print substring then H (without newlines)
 |                   afterwards (actually or, but p always returns 0)
           >GJ       substring: G[J:] (everything from index J to end)
                     update G with ^
                   afterwards implicitly print the remainder G
```

Comment: @isaacg Help? There must be something shorter...

Comment: And more elegant ;-)

Comment: Got it in 14 - 1 less than CJam is the best place to be.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 47 bytes

```
(w,s)=>w.replace(/./g,c=>c==s[0]?c+s.shift():c)
```

Assumes `s` is an array `["c","a","l","n"]`

Answer (score 3):

### [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <strike>68</strike> 34 Bytes

```
ri&:o&:&=\
l&io& /!?/
?!;20.\l!\
```

You can run it at [http://fishlanguage.com/playground](http://fishlanguage.com/playground/Libf2RavJY5mHi7iT) inputting the string as the initial stack (with " marks, i.e. "chameleon") and the array of extra letters as the input stack (no " marks i.e. caln).

Don't forget to press the Give button to seed the input stack.

```
r       reverses the stack
i&      reads in the first input, and stores it in the register
:o      copies the top of the stack, and outputs the top of the stack
&:&     puts register value on stack, copies it, then puts top stack into register
=       checks if the top two values are equal, if yes push 1, else push 0
?       if top value is non-zero, execute next instruction
!       skips the following instruction (unless it was skipped by the previous ?)

If yes, then we proceed on the same line
&o      puts register value on stack, and outputs it
i&      reads in the first input, and stores it in the register
l       puts length of stack on stack, then proceed to lowest line

If no, we go directly to the last line
l       As above.
?!;     If zero value (from length), then end execution
20.     Push 2 and 0 onto stack, then pop top two values, and go to that position (2,0) (i.e. next instruction is at (3,0))
```

EDIT: Halved it! :)

Answer (score 3):

## REGXY, 24 bytes

Uses [REGXY](http://esolangs.org/wiki/REGXY), a regex substitution based language. Input is assumed to be the starting word and the array, space separated (e.g. "chameleon caln").

```
/(.)(.* )\1| /\1\1\2/
//
```

The program works by matching a character in the first string with the first character after a space. If this matches, the character is repeated in the substitution and the character in the array is removed (well, not appended back into the string). Processing moves on to the second line, which is just a pointer back to the first line, which causes processing to repeat on the result of the previous substitution. Eventually, there will be no characters after the space, at which point the second branch of the alternation will match, removing the trailing space from the result. The regex will then fail to match, processing is completed and the result is returned.

If it helps, the iterative steps of execution are as follows:

```
chameleon caln
cchameleon aln
cchaameleon ln
cchaameleonn n
cchaameleonn  (with trailing space)
cchaameleonn
```

The program compiles and executes correctly with the sample interpreter in the link above, but the solution is perhaps a bit cheeky as it relies on an assumption in the vagueness of the language specification. The spec states that the first token on each line (before the /) acts as a label, but the assumption is that a null label-pointer will point back to the first command in the file with a null label (or in other words, that 'null' is a valid label). A less cheeky solution would be:

```
a/(.)(.* )\1| /\1\1\2/
b//a
```

Which amounts to 27 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>10</s> 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
iVvUèVÎ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=aVZ2VehWzg&input=ImJhbmFuYSIKWyJuIiwiYSJd)

```
iVvUèVÎ     :Implicit map of each character U in the first input (the string)
i           :Prepend
 V          :  The second input (the array)
  v         :  Remove this many elements from the start ...
   Uè       :    Count the occurrences in U of
     VÎ     :    The first element of V
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <del>52</del> 47 bytes

**Solution:**

`f=->(s,a){s.chars.map{|c|c==a[0]?a.shift*2:c}.join}`

**Example:**

`p f.call('banana', ['n','a']) # => "bannaana"`

**Explanation:**

Proc form of a method which takes a string as the first argument, and an array of characters as the second argument.  Maps a block onto an array of the characters in the string argument, which checks each character against first element of the comparison array, and if there is a match, removes the first element of the comparison array, and doubles it.

---

*update*

`f=->s,a{s.chars.map{|c|c==a[0]?a.shift*2:c}*''}`

Comment: You can skip the parentheses around the parameters `s,a`. And `*''` is equivalent to `.join`. That's 5 bytes saved, but I still [beat](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52081/4372) you by one (for now) :D

Answer (score 2):

## R, 119

Based on @Alex's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52013/41782), this one is a couple of bytes shorter:

```
function(s,a){message(unlist(lapply(strsplit(s,"")[[1]],function(x){if(length(a)&x==a[1]){a<<-a[-1];c(x,x)}else x})))}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function(s, a) {
  message(                             # Prints to output
    unlist(                            # Flattens list to vector
      lapply(                          # R's version of map
        strsplit(s,"")[[1]],           # Split vector to characters
        function (x) {
          if (length(a) & x == a[1]) { # If there are still elements in a
                                       # and there's a match
            a <<- a[-1]                # Modify a
            c(x, x)                    # And return the repeated character
          } else x                     # Otherwise just return it
        }
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>73</s> <s>62</s> <s>59</s> 56

Entirely new approach yields much better results. Still, I bet it can be shorter.

Call as `f('coconut', ['c','o'])`.

```
sub f{($s,$a)=@_;$s=~s/(.*?)($_)/\U$1$2$2/ for@$a;lc$s}
```

For each character in the array, find the first occurrence and duplicate it, and turn everything up to it to uppercase. Then return the entire string, converted to lowercase.

EDIT: shaved a couple of more characters by getting rid of `shift` and `pop`.

---

The previous version:

```
sub f{join '',map{shift @{$_[0]}if s/($_[0][0])/$1$1/;$_}split //,shift}
```

Comment: The new version doesn't respect the character order anymore. (BTW, “The `foreach` keyword is actually a synonym for the `for` keyword, so you can use either.” – [Foreach Loops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops).)

Comment: @manatwork That should do it. And thanks for the `for` hint. It's actually shorter now.

Answer (score 1):

## rs, 39 bytes

[More information about rs.](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs)

There's already a Retina answer, but I think this one uses a slightly different approach. They were also created separately: when I began working on this one, that answer hadn't been posted.

Besides, this one is 6 bytes longer anyway. :)

```
#
+#(\S)(\S*) ((\1)|(\S))/\1\4#\2 \5
#/
```

[Live demo and test suite.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%23%0A%2B%23(%5CS)(%5CS*)%20((%5C1)%7C(%5CS))%2F%5C1%5C4%23%5C2%20%5C5%0A%23%2F%0A&input=chameleon%20caln%0Aabcdefghij%20abc%0Alizard%20iard%0Acoconut%20co%0Aonomatopoeia%20ooaoo%0Aonomatopoeia%20oao%0A)

Comment: I really like that debug switch in your interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 77

```
def f(x,y,b=''):
 for i in x:
    try:
     if i==y[0]:i=y.pop(0)*2
    except:0
    b+=i
 print b
```

Call as:

```
f('onomatopoeia',['o','a','o'])
```

I may have got the byte count horribly wrong... Uses a mixture of spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 72 bytes

```js
(s,a,i=0,b=[...s])=>a.map(l=>b.splice(i=b.indexOf(l,i+2),0,l))&&b.join``
```

This is an anonymous function that takes 2 parameters: the starting word as a string and the characters to stretch as an array. Ungolfed code that uses ES5 and test UI below.

```js
f=function(s,a){
  i=0
  b=s.split('')
  a.map(function(l){
    i=b.indexOf(l,i+2)
    b.splice(i,0,l)
  })
  return b.join('')
}

run=function(){document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=f(document.getElementById('s').value,document.getElementById('a').value.split(''))};document.getElementById('run').onclick=run;run()
```

```html
<label>Starting word: <input type="text" id="s" value="onomatopoeia" /></label><br />
<label>Leters to duplicate: <input type="text" id="a" value="oao"/></label><br />
<button id="run">Run</button><br />Output: <output id="output"></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>136</s> <s>128</s> 122 bytes

```r
function(s,a){p=strsplit(s,"")[[1]];for(i in 1:nchar(s))if(length(a)&&(x=p[i])==a[1]){p[i]=paste0(x,x);a=a[-1]};message(p)}
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts a string and a character vector as input and prints a string to STDOUT. To call it, give it a name.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
f <- function(s, a) {
    # Split s into letters
    p <- strsplit(s, "")[[1]]

    # Loop over the letters of s
    for (i in 1:nchar(s)) {

        # If a isn't empty and the current letter is the first in a
        if (length(a) > 0 && p[i] == a[1]) {

            # Replace the letter with itself duplicated
            p[i] <- paste0(p[i], p[i])

            # Remove the first element from a
            a <- a[-1]
        }
    }

    # Combine p back into a string and print it
    message(p)
}
```

Examples:

```r
> f("coconut", c("c","o"))
ccooconut

> f("onomatopoeia", c("o","a","o"))
oonomaatoopoeia
```

Saved 8 bytes thanks to MickeyT and another 3 thanks to jja!

Comment: You could use `cat(p,sep='')` to output straight to STDOUT for a couple

Comment: @MickyT: Didn't think of that! Thanks, edited. :)

Comment: Actually, `message(p)` is shorter.

Comment: @jja: I didn't know about `message`, that's awesome! Thanks! Edited to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash+sed, 51

```
sed "`sed 's/./s!^[^&]*&!\U\&&!;/g'<<<$1`s/.*/\L&/"
```

Input from stdin; characters to be doubled as a single argument:

```
$ echo chameleon | strtech caln
cchaamelleonn
```

This works by constructing a sed program from `$2` and then executing it against `$1`.  The sed program replaces the first occurrence of each replacement letter with two copies of its uppercase version, and downcases the whole lot at the end.  For the example above, the generated sed program is

```
s!^[^c]*c!\U&C!;s!^[^a]*a!\U&A!;s!^[^l]*l!\U&L!;s!^[^n]*n!\U&N!;s/.*/\L&/
```

pretty-printed:

```
# if only sed had non-greedy matching...
s!^[^c]*c!\U&C!
s!^[^a]*a!\U&A!
s!^[^l]*l!\U&L!
s!^[^n]*n!\U&N!
s/.*/\L&/
```

I use the uppercase to mark characters processed so far; this avoids re-doubling characters that have already been doubled, or applying a doubling earlier than the previous one.

Earlier version, before clarification that order of replacement list is significant (44 chars):

```
sed "`sed 's/./s!&!\U&&!;/g'<<<$1`s/.*/\L&/"
```

Comment: Incorrect. `strtech na <<< banana` outputs “baannana”, but first an occurrence on “n” should be doubled, only after that an occurrence of “a”.

Comment: In that case, I've misunderstood the question; it wasn't explicit that the ordering meant that prior letters should _not_ be doubled, simply that you would be _able_ to find a subsequent one to double.  I'll have a think about an alternative that satisfies this new requirement.

Comment: No problem, neither I got it right the first time. I suggest to delete your answer while thinking (you can undelete any time later), to avoid the chance to get downvoted.

Comment: @manatwork: I've asked the questioner for clarification, and provided an alternative answer that satisfies that reading of the rules (but it cost me 7 chars to do so)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 92 characters

```
function f(s,c){r="";for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){r+=s[i];if(c.indexOf(s[i])>-1)r+=s[i]}return r}
```

Unobfuscated version:

```
function stretch(str, chars) {
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        ret += str[i];
        if(chars.indexOf(str[i]) > -1) {
            ret += str[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 51 bytes

```
$s=<>;$s=~s=^.*$_=$_=,$,.=$&for split"",<>;print$,;
```

Input is provided via STDIN. First input is the starting word (e.g. `chameleon`), second input is the letters as a single string (e.g. `caln`).

The above is just an obfuscated (read "prettier") way of doing the following:

```
$word = <>;
for $letter(split "", <>) {
   $word =~ s/^.*$letter/$letter/;
   $result .= $&;
}
print $result;
```

As we go through each letter, we replace from the start of the word up to the letter in the source word with just the new letter, and append the match (stored in `$&`) to our result. Since the match includes the letter and then gets replaced with the letter, each letter ends up appearing twice.

Because STDIN appends a new line character to both of our inputs, we're guaranteed to capture the remnants of the full word on the last match, i.e. the new line character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-0p`, 26 bytes

```perl
1while s;(.)(.+
)\1;$1$1$2
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiMXdoaWxlIHM7KC4pKC4rXG4pXFwxOyQxJDEkMiIsImFyZ3MiOiItMHAiLCJpbnB1dCI6ImJhbmFuYVxubmEifQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>41</s> 21 bytes

-20 bytes by adapting my answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217690/speed-of-lobsters/218688#218688)

```
{x@&y{y_x,1+y~:*x}/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6qucFCrrK6Mr9Ax1K6ss9KqqNWvqOXiSotWSs5IzE3NSc3PU7JWSk7MyVOKBYkmJiWnpKalZ2RmAYWBHIhoTmZVYlEKUCQTRIGFkvOT8/NKS0Ca8yEi+Xn5uYkl+QX5qZmJQOH8/MR8HDKJIHEA2J8znA==)

- `y{...}/x` set up a reduction seeded with `y` (the characters to repeat), run over the characters in `x` (the full string). confusingly, within the function itself, `x` and `y` are flipped. this ends up returning a boolean array with `2`s in the positions containing the desired matches and `1`s everywhere else

  - `1+y~:*x` compare the first character to search for (`*x`) to the current character being iterated over (`y`), updating `y` with the result of `0` or `1`. then add one to this; this represents the number of copies of the current character to end up returning. note that as soon as we have matched all the search characters, no more matches will be identified (since a character will never `~` (match) a `1` or `2`)
  - `x,` append this result to the list of characters to search for (essentially overloading the reduction to end up returning the desired output)
  - `y_` if there was a match, drop the first character (if there wasn't a match, this is a no-op). this allows us to search for the next search character in the next iteration of the reduction
- `x@&` return the correct number of copies of each character

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 9 bytes

```
£ƛ¥h=[&Ḣd
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiwqPGm8KlaD1bJuG4omQiLCIiLCJvb2Fvb1xub25vbWF0b3BvZWlhIl0=)

```
£ƛ¥h=[&Ḣd
£         # Put the first input in the register
 ƛ        # Map over the second input:
  ¥h=[    #  Is the current character equal to the first character of the register?
      &Ḣd #  If so, remove the first character of the register and double the current character
          #  (implicit) else, return the current character unchanged
          # s flag smashes this list into a string
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>53</s> 92 bytes

Found my solution to be the same length in both Python 2 and 3.

EDIT: Man, fixing that case when doing multiple replaces of the same letter (while still using the same method) took a bit of work.

#### Python 2:

[**Try it here**](http://ideone.com/DWTDDZ)

```python
def f(s,t):
 for c in t:s=s.replace(c,'%',1)
 print s.replace('%','%s')%tuple(x*2for x in t)
```

#### Python 3:

```python
s,*t=input()
for c in t:s=s.replace(c,'%',1)
print(s.replace('%','%s')%tuple(x*2for x in t))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, <s>76</s> <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> <s>58</s> 53 bytes

New, completely reworked solution with help from wieselkatze and SquidDev! come on guys, we can beat brainfuck :P

```
function f(a,b)print((a:gsub("["..b.."]","%1%1")))end
```

Explanation coming tommorow. [Try it here.](https://repl.it/tpW/1)

---

Original solution:
Saved 2 bytes thanks to @kirbyfan64sos!

Lua is a pretty terrible language to golf in, so I think I did pretty good for this one.

```
function f(x,y)for i=1,#x do g=y:sub(i,i)x=x:gsub(g,g..g,1)end print(x)end
```

Code explanation, along with ungolfed version:

```
function f(x,y) --Define a function that takes the arguements x and y (x is the string to stretch, y is how to stretch it)
  for i=1,#x do --A basic for loop going up to the length of x
    g=y:sub(i,i) -- Define g as y's "i"th letter
    x=x:gsub(g,g..g,1) --Redefine x as x with all letter "g"s having an appended g after them, with a replace limit of 1.
  end
  print(x)
end
```

[Try it here. (Outdated code but same concept, just less golfed, will update tommorow)](https://repl.it/tfG/1)

Comment: Added on two bytes because I had to fix glitch where it would replace all letter defined in the array with their duplicates.

Comment: I think you can remove the newlines after `function f(x,y)` and after `print(x)`, saving you two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 66 bytes

```
""<>Fold[Most@#~Join~StringSplit[Last@#,#2->#2<>#2,2]&,{"",#},#2]&
```

Example:

```
In[1]:= f = ""<>Fold[Most@#~Join~StringSplit[Last@#,#2->#2<>#2,2]&,{"",#},#2]&

In[2]:= f["banana", {"n", "a"}]

Out[2]= "bannaana"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

```
f=->s,a{a.map{|c|y,s=s.split(c,2);y+c*2}*''+s}
```

For each character `c` in the array `a`, divide the string `s` in two halves on the first occurrence of `c`. Add two copies of the `c` to the first half, and continue with the other half of `s`. Join it all together and add the remainder of `s` :)

Examples:

```
f["coconut", %w(c o)]
=> "ccooconut"
f["banana", %w(b a a)]
=> "bbaanaana"
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 57

Inspired by [BrainSteel's answer](/a/52001):

```
f(char*s,char*c){while(*c-putchar(*s++)||putchar(*c++));}
```

This uses the result of `putchar` to determine whether we've hit one of the replacement list, and if so, advance one through the replacement list, outputting as we go.

If we don't consume all the replacements, we'll go off the end of the input string, but luckily the rules guarantee we wont.  :-)

#### Test harness:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    f(argv[1], argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *This code assumes no double letters in the replacement list.* I don't think that's an assumption you are allowed to make, as the 4th test case has double letters. That is what drove me away from this approach :(

Comment: @BrainSteel - I've withdrawn the answer that makes the assumption "no double letters in the replacement list", and edited this to a new answer.  I can no longer avoid 2x`putchar`, but I save a few chars by using their results.

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 116 bytes

Indented for clarity:

```
string F(string s,string c){
    int i;
    return c==""
        ?s
        :s.Remove(i=s.IndexOf(c[0]))+c[0]+F(s.Substring(i),c.Substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SM83/Z80 machine language, 14 bytes

Takes input 1 in `de`, input 2 in `hl`, output to `bc`.

```
1A 13 02 03 B7 C8 BE 20
F7 02 03 23 18 F2
```

```
stretch:
 ld a,(de)                  // 1A       load input 1 char
 inc de                     // 13       and increment
 ld (bc),a                  // 02       store it
 inc bc                     // 03       and increment
 or a                       // B7       test for 0
 ret z                      // C8       return if so
 cp (hl)                    // BE       test against input 2 char
 jr nz,stretch              // 20 F7    if not same, continue
 ld (bc),a                  // 02       if same, store again
 inc bc                     // 03       and increment again
 inc hl                     // 23       also increment input 2 char
 jr stretch                 // 18 F2    loop back
```

The register pressure is extreme on this one. There's just enough room for three pointers and a character without pushing things to memory. It's impossible to do it this efficiently without putting the second input into `hl`.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 145 Bytes

```
  <?php
$a=str_split($argv[1]);
$b=str_split($argv[2]);
foreach($a as $x){
if($x==$b[0])
{
    $w[] = $x . $x;
    array_shift($b);
}
else $w[] = $x;
}
echo implode($w);
```

[Link to compact version](https://tio.run/##ZYwxDgIhFER7T0HxC2iM2iLxIIRsPrsgJBgIbFx049m/FHY2k8x7kymhEF1vJZQDoGprnVpJceWA9f7UZyMk2D98Gdjn6nAOgzBsDLrYo@fQlQKrT0bssGmjoLPjcBJrxdfUQvTjwgr5cak59puMNofM4qOkvDgOm5BElOIb60JxxBc)

Definitely not the shortest answer, but no one else has done PHP yet so why not!
Takes the word as the first argument, and a string representing the characters to be duplicated for the second argument.

I'm still new to golfing, so let me know if you see anything I could improve.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
vy?¬yQić?
```

Pretty similar to my 05AB1E answer for two related challenges: [Speed of Lobsters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217695/52210) and [Backronymiser](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249812/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/rNL@0JrKwMwj7fb//ycl5gEhV7RSnpKOUqJSLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##fY09DsIwDIWvUnnuHXIG5qoSzg80KI1RW5CC1LXsnIOZA1SchIsEJykrst7w3mf70YjSmngNAqrP8qhAhP2Y7PoMO/u@izjP60vEpgHVYW@cIQ81G6gBWY7loW05kuh5EvQZ5hCl0uZw7OwpgXQhWapAZ2846ATs9m5g6QIVKfKX6VdGJSVPPU50JmNzFWVUjun/Gm64/QI).

**Explanation:**

```python
v        # Loop over the characters `y` of the first (implicit) input-string:
 y?      #  Print this character
 ¬       #  Push the first letter of the list
         #  (which will be the second implicit input-list in the first iteration)
  yQi    #  If it's equal to the current character `y`:
     ć   #   Extract the head of the list
      ?  #   Pop and print it as well
```